# How to define an array in VxWorks Shell?

Tags: arrays, shell, vxworks

How can I define an array in VxWorks shell?
For example if I want to have the following:

```
myArray[3] = {1,2,3};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure you can, directly. You may be able to allocate some memory using eg malloc though, and then set the memory according to the values you want - something like the below should do

```
//Allocate the array
-> myArray = malloc( 3 )   
// use the m Command to edit the memory
-> m &myArray 
// do this for each element you want to set
-> 0x12ff3120 1
-> 0x12ff3121 2
// Check the memory
d &myArray
-> 0x12ff3120:             0001 0002 0003 0000
```

This works assuming you want an array of char sized elements. For other sizes, modifiy the m command to edit in eg word sized blocks:

```
->m &myArray 4
```

Comment: then, a bit cumbersome if I want to do this every time in shell!! Better to do this in my code.... thanks!